# Convert SRT to SUB/IDX and change font and background

Tags: subtitles

I have a TV with a built-in video player that plays from a USB flash, and it supports both .srt and .sub files. But it shows SRT subtitles with a small font, white color and no background.

I know SRT files support setting the font using `<font>`, but the TV's player ignores those tags (I tried).

So now **I'm wondering if I can convert the SRT to a SUB/IDX**, and then change the font and background (make the font bigger, and add a black or semi-transparent background)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Download [SubtitleEdit](https://github.com/SubtitleEdit/subtitleedit/releases/latest). Install and open it. drag your *.srt file on it. Go to file > export > vobsub

[image]

Adjust the font size and other settings. click on "export all lines"

[image]

Comment: Any alternative on Mac? Either GUI or CLI.