Can ffmpeg add a .srt subtitle file to a “.ts” file?
I have a .srt file with subtitles I want to add as a separate stream in a .ts file.
If I first convert this .srt file to a VobSub format I am able to add the subtitle .idx file like this:
ffmpeg -probesize 60M -analyzeduration 60M ^
-i "V808.ts" ^
-i "V808.[2357](41001ms).idx" ^
-map 0 -map 1 -vcodec copy -acodec copy -c:s:0 copy -c:s:1 dvbsub ^
-metadata:s:s:0 language=eng -metadata:s:s:0 handler_name=Bad -metadata:s:s:0 title=Bad ^
-metadata:s:s:1 language=eng -metadata:s:s:1 handler_name=Good -metadata:s:s:1 title=Good ^
OUTPUT.ts

However, I am unable to simply add the .srt file to the .ts file and would like to understand why.
This is the command I am trying:
-i "input.ts" ^
-i "subtitles.srt" ^
-map 0 -map 1 -vcodec copy -acodec copy -c:s:0 copy -c:s:1 copy -c:s:2 mov_text ^
-metadata:s:s:0 language=eng -metadata:s:s:0 handler_name=Name1 -metadata:s:s:0 title=Name1 ^
-metadata:s:s:1 language=eng -metadata:s:s:1 handler_name=Name2 -metadata:s:s:1 title=Name2 ^
-metadata:s:s:1 language=eng -metadata:s:s:1 handler_name=Name3 -metadata:s:s:1 title=Name3 ^
"output.ts"

I get this ffmpeg output:
ffmpeg -probesize 60M -analyzeduration 60M ^
More? -i "input.ts" ^
More? -i "output.srt" ^
More? -map 0 -map 1 -vcodec copy -acodec copy -c:s:0 copy -c:s:1 copy -c:s:2 mov_text ^
More? -metadata:s:s:0 language=eng -metadata:s:s:0 handler_name=Name1 -metadata:s:s:0 title=Name1 ^
More? -metadata:s:s:1 language=eng -metadata:s:s:1 handler_name=Name2 -metadata:s:s:1 title=Name2 ^
More? -metadata:s:s:1 language=eng -metadata:s:s:1 handler_name=Name3 -metadata:s:s:1 title=Name3 ^
More? "output.ts"
ffmpeg version 7.0.2-full_build-www.gyan.dev Copyright (c) 2000-2024 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 13.2.0 (Rev5, Built by MSYS2 project)
  configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-static --disable-w32threads --disable-autodetect --enable-fontconfig --enable-iconv
 --enable-gnutls --enable-libxml2 --enable-gmp --enable-bzlib --enable-lzma --enable-libsnappy --enable-zlib --enable-librist --enable-libsr
t --enable-libssh --enable-libzmq --enable-avisynth --enable-libbluray --enable-libcaca --enable-sdl2 --enable-libaribb24 --enable-libaribca
ption --enable-libdav1d --enable-libdavs2 --enable-libuavs3d --enable-libxevd --enable-libzvbi --enable-librav1e --enable-libsvtav1 --enable
-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxavs2 --enable-libxeve --enable-libxvid --enable-libaom --enable-libjxl --enable-libo
penjpeg --enable-libvpx --enable-mediafoundation --enable-libass --enable-frei0r --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-libharfbu
zz --enable-liblensfun --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvmaf --enable-libzimg --enable-amf --enable-cuda-llvm --enable-cuvid --enable-dxva2 -
-enable-d3d11va --enable-d3d12va --enable-ffnvcodec --enable-libvpl --enable-nvdec --enable-nvenc --enable-vaapi --enable-libshaderc --enabl
e-vulkan --enable-libplacebo --enable-opencl --enable-libcdio --enable-libgme --enable-libmodplug --enable-libopenmpt --enable-libopencore-a
mrwb --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libshine --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libcodec2 --enable-libilb
c --enable-libgsm --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopus --enable-libspeex --enable-libvorbis --enable-ladspa --enable-libbs2b --enable
-libflite --enable-libmysofa --enable-librubberband --enable-libsoxr --enable-chromaprint
  libavutil      59.  8.100 / 59.  8.100
  libavcodec     61.  3.100 / 61.  3.100
  libavformat    61.  1.100 / 61.  1.100
  libavdevice    61.  1.100 / 61.  1.100
  libavfilter    10.  1.100 / 10.  1.100
  libswscale      8.  1.100 /  8.  1.100
  libswresample   5.  1.100 /  5.  1.100
  libpostproc    58.  1.100 / 58.  1.100
[mpegts @ 0000024c425e1d00] PES packet size mismatch
[mpegts @ 0000024c425e1d00] Packet corrupt (stream = 1, dts = 8522036508).
[mpegts @ 0000024c425e1d00] PES packet size mismatch
[mpegts @ 0000024c425e1d00] Packet corrupt (stream = 2, dts = 8522036508).
Input #0, mpegts, from 'input.ts':
  Duration: 02:46:58.18, start: 84671.804778, bitrate: 3163 kb/s
  Program 9220
  Stream #0:0[0x931]: Video: mpeg2video (Main) ([2][0][0][0] / 0x0002), yuv420p(tv, top first), 704x576 [SAR 16:11 DAR 16:9], 25 fps, 25 tbr
, 90k tbn
      Side data:
        cpb: bitrate max/min/avg: 15000000/0/0 buffer size: 1605632 vbv_delay: N/A
  Stream #0:1[0x932](eng): Audio: mp2 ([4][0][0][0] / 0x0004), 48000 Hz, stereo, s16p, 192 kb/s
  Stream #0:2[0x933](NAR): Audio: mp2 ([4][0][0][0] / 0x0004), 48000 Hz, stereo, s16p, 128 kb/s
  Stream #0:3[0x934](eng,eng): Subtitle: dvb_teletext (libzvbi_teletextdec) ([6][0][0][0] / 0x0006), 492x250
  Stream #0:4[0x935](eng): Subtitle: dvb_subtitle (dvbsub) ([6][0][0][0] / 0x0006)
Input #1, srt, from 'subtitles.srt':
  Duration: N/A, bitrate: N/A
  Stream #1:0: Subtitle: subrip (srt)
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (copy)
  Stream #0:1 -> #0:1 (copy)
  Stream #0:2 -> #0:2 (copy)
  Stream #0:3 -> #0:3 (copy)
  Stream #0:4 -> #0:4 (copy)
  Stream #1:0 -> #0:5 (subrip (srt) -> mov_text (native))
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
Output #0, mpegts, to 'output.ts':
  Metadata:
    encoder         : Lavf61.1.100
  Stream #0:0: Video: mpeg2video (Main) ([2][0][0][0] / 0x0002), yuv420p(tv, top first), 704x576 [SAR 16:11 DAR 16:9], q=2-31, 25 fps, 25 tb
r, 90k tbn
      Side data:
        cpb: bitrate max/min/avg: 15000000/0/0 buffer size: 1605632 vbv_delay: N/A
  Stream #0:1(eng): Audio: mp2 ([4][0][0][0] / 0x0004), 48000 Hz, stereo, s16p, 192 kb/s (default)
  Stream #0:2(NAR): Audio: mp2 ([4][0][0][0] / 0x0004), 48000 Hz, stereo, s16p, 128 kb/s
  Stream #0:3(eng): Subtitle: dvb_teletext ([6][0][0][0] / 0x0006), 492x250 (default)
      Metadata:
        handler_name    : Name1
        title           : Name1
  Stream #0:4(eng): Subtitle: dvb_subtitle ([6][0][0][0] / 0x0006)
      Metadata:
        handler_name    : Name3
        title           : Name3
  Stream #0:5: Subtitle: mov_text
      Metadata:
        encoder         : Lavc61.3.100 mov_text
[mpegts @ 0000024c42b98200] Timestamps are unset in a packet for stream 3. This is deprecated and will stop working in the future. Fix your
code to set the timestamps properly
[mpegts @ 0000024c42b98200] Stream 5, codec mov_text, is muxed as a private data stream and may not be recognized upon reading.
[dvbsub @ 0000024c425e6500] Junk in packet3145.2kbits/s speed=85.2x
[dvbsub @ 0000024c425e6500] Junk in packet3139.1kbits/s speed=68.5x
[dvbsub @ 0000024c425e6500] Junk in packet3079.0kbits/s speed= 118x
[dvbsub @ 0000024c425e6500] Junk in packet3119.3kbits/s speed= 172x
    Last message repeated 1 times
[dvbsub @ 0000024c425e6500] Junk in packet3124.2kbits/s speed= 177x
[dvbsub @ 0000024c425e6500] Junk in packet3156.2kbits/s speed= 218x
[dvbsub @ 0000024c425e6500] Junk in packet3187.6kbits/s speed= 212x
[dvbsub @ 0000024c425e6500] Junk in packet3165.9kbits/s speed= 245x
[dvbsub @ 0000024c425e6500] Junk in packet3149.8kbits/s speed= 264x
[dvbsub @ 0000024c425e6500] Junk in packet3172.2kbits/s speed= 298x
[dvbsub @ 0000024c425e6500] Junk in packet3179.6kbits/s speed= 294x
[dvbsub @ 0000024c425e6500] Junk in packet3175.3kbits/s speed= 306x
[dvbsub @ 0000024c425e6500] Junk in packet3195.0kbits/s speed= 307x
[dvbsub @ 0000024c425e6500] Junk in packet3175.7kbits/s speed= 318x
[mpegts @ 0000024c425e1d00] PES packet size mismatchs/s speed= 327x
[mpegts @ 0000024c425e1d00] Packet corrupt (stream = 1, dts = 8522036508).
[in#0/mpegts @ 0000024c425e1980] corrupt input packet in stream 1
    Last message repeated 1 times
[mpegts @ 0000024c425e1d00] PES packet size mismatch
[mpegts @ 0000024c425e1d00] Packet corrupt (stream = 2, dts = 8522036508).
[in#0/mpegts @ 0000024c425e1980] corrupt input packet in stream 2
    Last message repeated 3 times
[out#0/mpegts @ 0000024c42b23500] video:3252315KiB audio:391193KiB subtitle:76606KiB other streams:0KiB global headers:0KiB muxing overhead:
 4.940417%
size= 3903904KiB time=02:46:34.70 bitrate=3199.8kbits/s speed= 330x

When I play the output.ts in VLC I cannot see the new subtitle stream to choose. Of note, the ffmpeg output states:
[mpegts @ 0000024c42b98200] Stream 5, codec mov_text, is muxed as a private data stream and may not be recognized upon reading.

I get the same error if I try the subrip codec.
Additionally, if I first create the .ts file without any subtitles streams and then convert it to a .mp4 file..
ffmpeg -probesize 60M -analyzeduration 60M -i "input.ts" -map 0 -c copy "output.mp4"

Then I AM able to add in the .srt file of subtitles without first needing to convert it to VobSub format...
ffmpeg -probesize 60M -analyzeduration 60M ^
-i "input.mp4" ^
-i "subtitles.srt" ^
-map 0 -map 1 -vcodec copy -acodec copy -c:s:0 mov_text ^
-metadata:s:s:0 language=eng -metadata:s:s:0 handler_name=Subs -metadata:s:s:0 title=Subs ^
"output.mp4"

My Question
Can ffmpeg add a .srt file of subtitles as a separate stream to a .ts file or is there no choice but to convert it to VobSub format first?

This question is similar to: Add an idx subtitle file as an additional stream to a “.ts” file?. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

I have done this already. The question is different because although in each case the goal is to add subtitles to a .ts file the approach is different... using a .srt file instead of a .idx file. The .idx file works with .ts files but the .srt file does not seem to but I am not sure and need help with that.

This will bridge the gap. If ffmpeg doesn't support srt, convert them to idx: https://superuser.com/questions/857716/convert-srt-to-sub-idx-and-change-font-and-background

Did you do any research info ffmpeg w/ srt support? There are guides online for building ffmpeg yourself with srt support: https://srtlab.github.io/srt-cookbook/apps/ffmpeg.html

@music2myear Thanks. Yes I came to that conclusion also. I made an answer for this below. But in this case the .srt refers to SubRip Subtitle.

To answer the question:
No ffmpeg cannot add a .srt file of subtitles to a .ts container.
With ffmpeg the only subtitles that are supported in Transport Stream containers are dvb_subtitle and dvb_teletext. Both are image-based.
If you want to add a text-based .srt file of subtitles to a .ts container they need to be converted to VobSub (.idx) format first. Tools like SubtitleEdit can do that conversion. Then use the dvbsub codec as described in the original question.
In my experience the metadata is not recognised in .ts containers, but it is in mp4 and mkv containers.
